# Versioned API with Swagger not detecting API operations

Tags: asp.net-core, swashbuckle, api-versioning

I implemented an API and integrated it with [Swagger](https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore).

Startup **ConfigureServices**:

```
services
    .AddMvcCore()
    .AddApiExplorer();

services.AddSwaggerGen(c => {
    c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new Info { 
        Title = "API", Version = "v1" 
    });
});
```

Startup **Configure**

```
app.UseSwagger(c => {
    c.RouteTemplate = "{documentName}/configuration.json";
});

app.UseSwaggerUI(c =>
{
     c.SwaggerEndpoint("/v1/configuration.json", "API");
     c.RoutePrefix = "v1/docs";
})
```

**Controller**

```
[Route("v1/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class SomeController : ControllerBase {}
```

## So far so good...

**Works like a charm. However my upgrade to the latest `[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Versioning.ApiExplorer][2]` doesn't**

I followed both the [samples](https://github.com/Microsoft/aspnet-api-versioning/tree/master/samples/aspnetcore/SwaggerSample) as well as the [documentation](https://github.com/Microsoft/aspnet-api-versioning/wiki/API-Documentation#aspnet-core) but I can't get my operations to show... **What am I missing here?**

Startup **ConfigureServices**

```
services
    .AddMvcCore()
    //.AddApiExplorer()
    .AddVersionedApiExplorer( o => o.GroupNameFormat = "'v'VVV" );

services.AddApiVersioning(o => o.ReportApiVersions = true);

services.AddSwaggerGen(c => {
//    c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new Info { 
//        Title = "API", Version = "v1" 
//    });

      foreach (var description in provider.ApiVersionDescriptions)
      {
          c.SwaggerDoc(
              description.GroupName,
              new Info()
              {
                  Title = $"API",
                  Version = description.ApiVersion.ToString()
              });
      }
      c.OperationFilter<SwaggerDefaultValues>();
});
```

*[SwaggerDefaultValues.cs](https://github.com/Microsoft/aspnet-api-versioning/blob/master/samples/webapi/SwaggerODataWebApiSample/SwaggerDefaultValues.cs)

Startup **Configure**

```
app.UseSwagger(c => {
    c.RouteTemplate = "{documentName}/configuration.json";
});

app.UseSwaggerUI(c =>
{
     c.SwaggerEndpoint("/v1/configuration.json", "API");
     c.RoutePrefix = "v1/docs";

     foreach (var description in apiProvider.ApiVersionDescriptions)
     {
         c.SwaggerEndpoint($"/{description.GroupName}/configuration.json", description.GroupName.ToUpperInvariant());
     }
})
```

**Controller**

```
//[Route("v1/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
[Route("v{version:apiVersion}/[controller]")]
[ApiVersion("1.0")]
public class SomeController : ControllerBase {}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is probably because you have commented out `.AddApiExplorer()` and you do not have a call to `.AddMvc()`. The call to `.AddMvcCore()` does **not** call `.AddApiExplorer()` nor does `.AddVersionedApiExplorer()` (which will changing in v3.0 to avoid this kind of issue). The call to `.AddMvc()` as shown in the examples **does** call `.AddApiExplorer()` indirectly. This is likely the cause and you just need to bring `.AddApiExplorer()` back into the fold.

In addition, is there a particular reason you are configuring:

```
c.SwaggerEndpoint("/v1/configuration.json", "API");
c.RoutePrefix = "v1/docs";
```

Not sure if that's affecting it, but shouldn't be necessary either.

Have you set breakpoints inside:

```
services.AddSwaggerGen(c => { … })
```

And

```
app.UseSwaggerUI(c => { … })
```

Within `AddSwaggerGen`, you should see at least one API description. Within `UseSwaggerUI`, you should see at least `1.0`. It's not clear how many versions you have at the moment.